# Viber won't connect to internet at startup

Tags: networking, debian, viber

I'm trying to install viber on my debian desktop computer and it displays me a message:

[image: viber error]

Operating system: debian jessie

just after I've written my phone number.

Details:

1. I don't think this is about "port opening" because mobile version works exactly from this connection. More: I've tried desktop from 3g network (from phone) and error is the same
2. I've dumped connection log (with tcpdump) and found that it do makes connections to amazon services (maybe Viber servers are hosted on amazon) and even receives some answers.

Any ideas? What else may I look?

Comment: you are not using proxy, correct?

Comment: Sure. No proxy.

Comment: and even though you already mention that this is not a problem with ports I guess there is no harm in confirming that the following ports are not used by any other application -  TCP: 5242 and 4244
UDP: 5243 and 9785

Comment: sudo netstat -plnt | grep 5242
sudo netstat -plnt | grep 4244
 -- nothing

any other way to be absolutely sure?

Comment: I know this is a stretch and doesn't make much sense but try launching viber from the terminal as root or sudo.

Comment: Tried. Same error =(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36276/discussion-between-jay-t-and-arenim).